# Implementing Email Verification process with GAE python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email-verification

I want to implement a simple registration to my app on google app engine.

I store the user email and password on the db and than i want to send an authentication email to the email the user have entered to verify if he is the actual owner of the address

i guess i will generate some GUID and store it in the DB
than have a handler  to handle the confirmation 
than check the email as verified once some one "get"s this link

something like:

```
myapp.appspot.com/verifyemail/you@domain.com/qCv4fUNJ4AVuNLSXDLDqEEoARGk
```

i'm sure someone has already implemented such thing or a similar

i would be grateful if you can link me to something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afair GAE is based on python-django, so there’s much information on this in the web.
Check for example: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/sep/02/django-tips-user-registration/

More is available if you google for: django email confirmation

Comment: App Engine is not based on Django, but you can use Django (with patching - see the Django-nonrel project) on App Engine.